# How do I find which range a value falls within in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to take the value written in the number field in table A and find which range it corresponds to in the high range and low range fields in table B and show it as in the result table. If in more than one range, it should take whichever comes first (B_id is smaller)

A table

| A_Id | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 60 |
| 4 | 52 |

for example( number = 10)

B table

| B_Id | Low range | High range | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 30 | ACARD |
| 2 | 35 | 55 | BCARD |
| 3 | 50 | 110 | CCARD |

for example( Low range >10 and high range <10  the result  B_id = 1)

Result Table

| Id | Number | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | ACARD |
| 2 | 50 | BCARD |
| 3 | 60 | CCARD |
| 4 | 52 | BCARD |

Comment: have you tried `INNER JOIN` + `ROW_NUMBER()` ?

Comment: No field  to join (Foreign Key)

Comment: You don't need a foreign key to perform a join. `A JOIN B ON A.Number BETWEEN B.LowRange and B.HighRange`

Comment: so how do i use row number

Comment: please do check the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following SQL.

The **`BETWEEN`** used to find the ranges and **`ROW_NUMBER`** helps to get the smaller value.

```
create table tableA(a_id int, Number int)
insert into tableA values(1,10)
insert into tableA values(2,50)
insert into tableA values(3,60)
insert into tableA values(4,52)

create table tableB(b_id int, lowRange int, highRange int, Rtype varchar(10))
insert into tableB values (1,5,30,'ACARD')
insert into tableB values (2,35,55,'BCARD')
insert into tableB values (3,50,110,'CCARD')

;with CTE AS(
select a.a_id Id, a.Number, b.Rtype, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.a_id ORDER BY LowRange) RN
from tableA A
inner join tableB B on A.Number between B.lowRange and B.highRange
)
select Id, Number, Rtype 
from CTE
where RN = 1

drop table tableA
drop table tableB
```

**Output:**

```
Id          Number      Rtype
----------- ----------- ----------
1           10          ACARD
2           50          BCARD
3           60          CCARD
4           52          BCARD
```